# Online php chatrooms load chat without web sockets

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, sockets

I designed my chatting panel , but the problem is that users need to refresh them every time to load the new messages.

I learned that I need to implement web sockets to load them automatically , but I observed Php chatrooms ([this chat for instance](https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/)) scripted that I downloaded from internet displays the messages on the receiver side without any refresh, and for that I didn't applied any web sockets.

How is it possible?

Comment: Short answer: AJAX. Just google it.

Comment: Well, if you actually read the link you posted, it explains how to achieve whatever you want.